# Replaced files are not replaced on server (cPanel)

Tags: php, html, server, cpanel

So this is my problem. I replace an image with the same name on server (cpanel) and it is still showing the old image, this is happening with other files too, and even if I delete the image it is still there on the site. How do I fix this?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try.

Comment: I did, but still not working

Comment: What does your code look like... There's a lot of reasons for you to see something like that.

Comment: @BrunoErceg can you SSH into the server?

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser? That will make sure there's nothing cached

Comment: I did, I even try from different devices, everywhere the same. I think its something with the server

Answer (score 0):

Clear everything. 
Even if you think you have, just be safe and clear your cookies and cached images for your site.

The other possibility is that you've named it the same but with a wrong case. Remember HTML and PHP is case sensitive when looking at file names.

Let me know after you've attempted these.

Comment: I did, I tried from different browsers and even devices, but everywhere is the same

Comment: @BrunoErceg My only thought then would be you're accessing your server without the proper SSH key, so you may be able to visually see things but you're unable to make proper changes.
What host are you using?
Did you set up SSH(SFTP) or are you just using plain FTP?